# Activating conda environment by name from within snakemake workflow

Tags: python-3.x, conda, snakemake

Detailed info here, tl;dr can be found towards the end...

I've got a bioinformatics workflow I run using `snakemake`, with a python3 wrapper script using the `snakemake` API so that the `snakemake` command is simplified (https://github.com/charlesfoster/covid-illumina-snakemake). Most necessary programs are installed in a 'master' conda environment, while other programs with incompatible dependencies are installed in dedicated environments using `conda` directives within snakemake rules.

However, some programs cannot be easily included in this manner because they have a more complex installation. An example is `pangolin` (https://github.com/cov-lineages/pangolin), which requires the `pangolin` repo to be cloned, a conda environment created, then a "`pip install .`". Then, to run `pangolin` within the workflow, I have the following rule:

```
rule pangolin:
    input:
        fasta=os.path.join(RESULT_DIR, "{sample}/variants/{sample}.consensus.fa"),
    output:
        report=os.path.join(RESULT_DIR, "{sample}/pangolin/{sample}.lineage_report.csv"),
    shell:
        """
        set +eu
        eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)" && conda activate pangolin && pangolin --outfile {output.report} {input.fasta} &> /dev/null
        set -eu
        """
```

I've also tried the new named conda environment directive as of `snakemake` version ~6.15.5:

```
rule pangolin:
    input:
        fasta=os.path.join(RESULT_DIR, "{sample}/variants/{sample}.consensus.fa"),
    output:
        report=os.path.join(RESULT_DIR, "{sample}/pangolin/{sample}.lineage_report.csv"),
    conda:
        "pangolin"
    shell:
        """
pangolin --outfile {output.report} {input.fasta} &> /dev/null

        """
```

Steps to run the workflow:

1. `conda activate CIS`
2. `CIS [options] directory_name/`

While this works on my main development PC, when I try to install the pipeline on a new computer, I end up getting the following error:

```
Could not find conda environment: pangolin
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

If I run `conda info --envs` manually within the terminal, I get the following:

```
$USER/Programs/covid-illumina-snakemake/.snakemake/conda/520fff074cd181af7ee385f2520fdd81
$USER/Programs/covid-illumina-snakemake/.snakemake/conda/cb6755e5de757f643e542e3ec52055b7
base                     $USER/miniconda3
CIS                   *  $USER/miniconda3/envs/CIS
pangolin                 $USER/miniconda3/envs/pangolin
```

If I run `conda info --envs` within the `snakemake` workflow itself, I get the following:

```
$USER/Programs/covid-illumina-snakemake/.snakemake/conda/520fff074cd181af7ee385f2520fdd81
$USER/Programs/covid-illumina-snakemake/.snakemake/conda/cb6755e5de757f643e542e3ec52055b7
$USER/miniconda3
base                  *  $USER/miniconda3/envs/CIS
$USER/miniconda3/envs/pangolin
```

(username redacted here in both for brevity)

So, as you can see, the names of the environments are no longer detected within the `snakemake` workflow, and the 'CIS' environment is incorrectly thought to be 'base'. Therefore, the `pangolin` conda environment cannot be activated by name with `eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)" && conda activate pangolin`.

**tl;dr:** `conda info --envs` has unexpected and different behaviour when invoked from within a `snakemake` workflow, which is 'driven' by a python script within a 'master' conda env.

Does anyone know why this might be, and/or how to fix it? Is there a better way to activate a named conda environment within a `snakemake` workflow?

Thanks!

`snakemake` version: 6.15.5

`conda` version: 4.11.0

Comment: Do you *need* a development install of pangolin (cloning the repo and all that song and dance) e.g. because you want to tinker with it, or would the simple installation with `conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c defaults  pangolin` do the job? If you need to update the databases or such separately, I think there's a way to point it at other dirs for the databases

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly I do need the development version, so the bioconda install doesn’t do the job. The bioconda version is missing several important major updates that go further than updated databases.

Comment: How so, out of curiosity? I'm aware of pangolearn on conda sometimes being somewhat behind, but as far as I can tell pangolin proper should be up to date with the latest release on github.

Comment: I agree with KeyboardCat - the latest release is [on Bioconda](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/pangolin/files), and historically tracks with almost no lag. For the sake of reproducibility, I strongly discourage Snakemake users from activating local Conda environments.

Comment: Thanks, both, for your comments. I only recently became aware of the conda installation of `pangolin`, and when I tried it, it was horribly outdated. However, I've looked further after your comments, and realised that an old version was being installed because of an incompatible python version in the fresh conda environment. I've now got around that and have an up-to-date `pangolin` install via conda, which gets around all the issues. Thanks!